# How to dynamically update a page with images generated via php GD

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, gd

Currently I am dynamically generating 1-(N) images via php GD based on user form input, and then posting into an iframe, that displays the image.

But theres a couple of problems:

1. Iframes seems to be a drag when styling.
2. The user dont seem to be able to "rightclick->saveas" the images properly when in iframes.

So are there any better methods for doing this?

Comment: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a fixed size `div` element with `overflow: scroll` set on it.

For example:

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll; //vertical scrolling only
}
```

It behaves in the same manner as an iframe, but allows you better control of both content via javascript and styling via CSS.